# What to do about "hanging" comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

Frequently I'll be on various SE sites and see directed comments in direct response to others. Sometimes I find these intriguing as to what triggered the response, but I scroll up to find that the original comment was deleted, leaving the response with no context or usefulness to it. This often makes the "hanging" response a bit confusing. Is there anything that can or should be done about this?

**Ideas**

1. Keep comments with direct responses from being deleted

*While this could be less confusing, if the original was not constructive, I understand the deletion*

2. Delete comments replying to deleted comments

*Many of them are no longer relevant anyway, as their purpose in being no longer is there*

3. Do nothing

*It's possible that most people aren't bothered by this, and it should just be left as-is*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the comment has value beyond being a reply (for example, if it links to something that would be relevant to improving the post), then leave it.  People know that comments get deleted, so while the unreferenced pointer will create some momentary confusion, most people will just shrug and move on.

If the comment has no remaining value, then flag it as "no longer needed".